# Add GeneralHtmlSupport not working ckeditor5 react

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

Add GeneralHtmlSupport throwing error [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phKjp.png)

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
import GeneralHtmlSupport from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support/src/generalhtmlsupport';

const editorConfiguration = {
        plugins: [ GeneralHtmlSupport ],
        
    };

<CKEditor
                                        editor={ Editor }      
                                        config={ editorConfiguration }                                                                                                         
                                        
                                    />
```

added online build and installed but nit worked